# How to get location updates via Google location client API?

Tags: android, google-maps, locationlistener

I want to create a Map app with location update listener. I have created one, it is working fine, but only in India, when i try to use it in US it will crash. I don't know what happen.I was send apk file to my friend who live in US. He has HTC one device.

I have checked it in my end with following devices:

1. htc desire 816.
2. nexus7.
3. samsung quarto.
4. samsung grand 2.

In all these devices my code is working fine.

here is my complete code:

```html
public class MapScreen extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{
 static LatLng CURRENT , SearchedPosition, LocationsAll;
 private GoogleMap map;
 EditText search;
 // TextView TitleTxt;
 // Boolean IsCallingLastSeen = true;
 //Location
 String currentUserdetailStr;
 public Marker currentUser;
 private static final String TAG = MapScreen.class.getSimpleName();

 private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

 private Location mLastLocation;

 // Google client to interact with Google API
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

 // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
 private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

 private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

 // Location updates intervals in sec
 private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
 private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
 private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters
 ///

 Typeface font;
 SessionManager session;
 RelativeLayout titleBar;
 //List<String> ll_StrNew;
 LinearLayout SearchLayout;
 CheckBox ShowSearch;
 JSONObjParser resultis;
 JSONObject jsonObj;
 String TheamColorDark = "0,187,210",phonenumber,stringLat,stringLong;
 String[] sinptArray,phonenumberAry;
 ImageView LogOutTxt;



 String stringLatitude;
 String stringLongitude;

 String searchStatus = "";

 int aColor,rColor,gColor,bColor;
 Double lat,lng;
 String[] colorArry;

 LatLng getLatLng;
 String currntAddress= "";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);

 
  //  addressAry.clear();
  try {

   // First we need to check availability of play services
   if (checkPlayServices()) {

    // Building the GoogleApi client
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    createLocationRequest();
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checkPlayServices", 1000).show();
  }

  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

  // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
  map = mapFragment.getMap();
  //LocationsAll

  session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

  //ll_StrNew = LoginScreen.ll_Str;

  //  TitleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TitleTxtMap);
  LogOutTxt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.LogoutImageView);
  titleBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.TitleBarMap);
  SearchLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SearchLayout);

  ShowSearch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxSearch);

  Log.w("session == ", session.pref.getString("login_status", "").toString());

  try {

   GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

   if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation())
   {
    stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
    stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);


   }
   else
   {
    gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gpsTracker", 1000).show();
  }

  try {

   Handler h = new Handler();
   h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
    }
   }, 5000); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "togglePeriodicLocationUpdates", 1000).show();
  }
  
  
  CURRENT = (new LatLng(locationsLat.get(locationsLat.size()-1), locationsLong.get(locationsLat.size()-1)));


  font = LoginScreen.FinalfontFamily;

  //  TitleTxt.setTypeface(font);

  

  search=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBarEdit);


   // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CURRENT, 15));

   // Zoom in, animating the camera.
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18), 1000, null);
   //   map.isMyLocationEnabled();
   //   map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

   currentUser = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(CURRENT)
   .title(currentUserdetailStr)
   .snippet("+1 "+main_numberAry.get(main_numberAry.size()-1))
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_pin)));
   // Drawing circle on the map
   drawCircle(CURRENT);
  }
  map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String strPhone = arg0.getSnippet().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    if (strPhone.equals("Not available") ) {

    }
    else
    {
     Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
     smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

     smsIntent.putExtra("address"  , strPhone);
     smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body"  , "Test SMS");
     try {
      startActivity(smsIntent);
      Log.i("Finished sending SMS...", "");
     } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      Toast.makeText(MapScreen.this, 
        "SMS faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }
   }
  });

  map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

   // Use default InfoWindow frame
   @Override
   public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
    return null;
   }

   // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
   @Override
   public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

    // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

    // Getting reference to the TextView to set name
    TextView PersonName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.personName);

    // Getting reference to the TextView to set phone
    TextView phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumberTextView);

    PersonName.setText(arg0.getTitle());
    phone.setText(arg0.getSnippet());

    phone.setTypeface(LoginScreen.FinalfontFamily);
    PersonName.setTypeface(LoginScreen.FinalfontFamily);

    // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
    return v;

   }
  });
 }
 private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String name, String phone){
  // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

  // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
  markerOptions.position(point);
  markerOptions.title(name);
  markerOptions.snippet(phone);
  // Adding marker on the Google Map
  map.addMarker(markerOptions);
 }
 
 
 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  try {

   if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  try {

   checkPlayServices();

   // Resuming the periodic location updates
   if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
    startLocationUpdates();
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  try {

   if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  try {

   stopLocationUpdates();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 /**
  * Method to display the location on UI
  * */
 private void displayLocation() {
  try {


   mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
     .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

   if (mLastLocation != null) {
    double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
    double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

    //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location changed", 1000).show();
    new LastSeenProgressTask(MapScreen.this,latitude,longitude).execute();

   } else {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)", 1000).show();
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 /**
  * Method to toggle periodic location updates
  * */
 private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
  try {

   if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
    // Changing the button text

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

    // Starting the location updates
    startLocationUpdates();

    Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");
   }
   else {
    // Changing the button text
    //   btnStartLocationUpdates
    //   .setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    // Stopping the location updates
    stopLocationUpdates();

    Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "togglePeriodicLocationUpdates function", 1000).show();
  }
 }

 /**
  * Creating google api client object
  * */
 protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
  try {

   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
   .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
   .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GoogleApiClient.Builder", 1000).show();
  }
 }

 /**
  * Creating location request object
  * */
 protected void createLocationRequest() {
  try {

   mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
   mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
   mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
   mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
   mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 /**
  * Method to verify google play services on the device
  * */
 private boolean checkPlayServices() {
  int resultCode = 0;
  try {
  
   resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GooglePlayServicesUtil", 1000).show();
  }
  if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
   if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
      PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
    finish();
   }
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }

 /**
  * Starting the location updates
  * */
 protected void startLocationUpdates() {
  try {


   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
     mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 /**
  * Stopping location updates
  */
 protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
  try {

   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
     mGoogleApiClient, this);


  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {

   mLastLocation = location;

   //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
   //    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   // Displaying the new location on UI
   displayLocation();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }
 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {

   Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
     + result.getErrorCode());
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }
 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {

   displayLocation();

   if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
    startLocationUpdates();
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }
 @Override
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }
}
```

Please tell me where i am wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can check this repo

https://github.com/Keshava11/droidutility

and use this [LocationUtil](https://github.com/Keshava11/droidutility/blob/libdroidutility/src/main/java/com/droidutility/location/utils/LocationClientUtil.java) class to get location updates.

Check **README** for LocationUtil usage. 
For regular updates you can check the **sendLocalLocationBroadcast()** method in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen crashes caused by onLocationChanged(Location location) receiving a null location parameter on some devices.

I'd remove the catch-everything exception handling in this method, and instead check for a null in the location of your onLocationChanged(Location location).

As a general design principle, you should avoid silently catching all exceptions, and instead report specific errors to the user or write to a debug log. Then you'll have more information to track down the cause of the crash.